# Apple sign-in only for Web portal

Tags: web-applications, apple-sign-in

I'm in the process of setting up Apple Sign-In for our web portal. The web portal doesn't have a related Apple application. I've been reviewing the documentation provided at https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/configure-sign-in-with-apple-for-the-web/ and attempting to set it up. It appears that this might not be possible without an existing Apple application associated with the web portal.

According to https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/configure-sign-in-with-apple-for-the-web/:

> To configure web authentication, you must create a Services ID and associate your website to an existing primary iOS, macOS, tvOS, or watchOS App ID enabled for Sign in with Apple.

Does this imply that it's not feasible without an existing Apple application?